# SSH Connection problems

Tags: server, openssh

I'm having troubles with a simple SSH Connection at home.

I installed openSSH on an Ubuntu Server. I generated the rsa and dsa but this ssh connection stops while expecting a MSG packaget that I don't understand. I previuosly installed no-ip and linked it to my network but I think this is not the problem.

```
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to blue-house.servebeer.com [87.221.76.172] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/miguel/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/miguel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/miguel/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/miguel/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/miguel/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/miguel/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.36
debug1: no match: dropbear_0.36
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client 3des-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server 3des-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

UPDATE 1: There is something related with dropbear_o.36 that is very old in my router.

Here a post an image that shows that I have no problems to connect straight with my IP, but with a DNS (I have set up 2, no-ip and freedns, but got the same result)

[image: screenshot]

I think I can't update my router firmware anymore...What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure, that your Ubuntu machine is answering, and not your router?

Answer (score 1):

This solved my similar problem:

```
apt-get install putty-tools
plink admin@routerip
...
Server version: SSH-2.0-dropbear_0.46
Using SSH protocol version 2
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Local:_Aug_11_2013_21:26:51
Using Diffie-Hellman with standard group "group1"
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 1040 d6:8f:96:ec:73:70:67:33:70:a7:52:a6:8a:2f:56:14
Initialised triple-DES CBC client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised triple-DES CBC server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
Using username "admin".
admin@10.1.0.150's password:
```